# Entity Framework Code First challenge: let's see if anyone can answer this :)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first, public

Is it possible (using EF Code First) to define a POCO class like

```
  public class Product
  {
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Description {get;set;}
  }
```

and have Name & Description values culture based stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can't design a POCO class that would store multiple values in one database column and pick the right one based on a culture.

What you could do is add a lookup class where ProductId and CultureId are the combined primary key and store a culture specific name and description for each product.

You could abstract this away in your repository by giving back a list of flattened products for the current culture or adding a Name and Description property in a partial product class and let them use the current culture to look up the culture based values.

Comment: The question is how to define the POCO class(es) so it will create the right tables based on the Code First approach. Your approach is to create the database objects first(lookup table).

Comment: A simple association to a class holding name/description would translate into a lookup table in your database. The two properties making up the primary key would be something you specify in your fluent mappings and the Repository/partial class would be in code.

Comment: So are you saying if I have 50 domain classes I'll end up with 100 domain classes? 

So for Product class I'll have a lookup table like ProductLanguage [ProductId, LanguageId,Name,Description] ?

If yes, is the ProductLanguage a real Domain class?

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a domain class.. more a 'helper class'. I'm also not sure if this is really the way you want to go.. Maybe you could have one Resource table and do a look up in that one table, so your classes won't double?